# Should the title be included in the question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

In [How does Captain America's Shield harness work?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63367/how-does-captain-americas-shield-harness-work) The question acts as if the title is the first sentence by continuing with "I am referring specifically to the MCU version"

Often, i open up a number of questions i want to read and then *skip the title* when reading them. This almost always works, but for questions like the above, i need to re-read the title.

This leads me to wonder:

1. Should the title be included in the question (in some form) or can the question be treated as continuing from the title.
2. If the title is a summary, would it be better if the Title field were under the question (above tags), so the user summarized what has already ben asked rather than what he expects to ask?

Comment: I searched for "included" rather than "repeated". That's why i didn't find it. Nonetheless, only one person answers it. Is that really the case? Most questions i have come across are written otherwise. Anyway, one thing that is not addressed there is, can the question continue from the title? That point is not really addressed there.

Comment: The answer states: *It should be **expanded** in the question body*; e.g. the title is a summary, a short short version of the question. The body should stand independently, really.

Comment: If it is a summary, shouldn't the title field be *under* the question field? Summaries tend to be written *after* the subject it is summarizing.

Comment: Is the title of a book or essay also written after the body of the text? Chapter titles? You want to see what is in the box, so to speak, before opening. But once you are reading the contents, the title should not be required to understand the text.

Comment: I understand that (but, the example i gave does not). I am asking question 2 now. Wouldn't the placement of the title field relative to the question field affect how the user who asks the question treats it? This would have no affect on the way it is displayed afterward to readers.

Comment: I really see no point in confusing the user with two different placements; showing the title on top but when you ask the question, placing it at the bottom.

Comment: Confusion. That is a good point. I *still* think the placement has an affect on its quality. But, at least i know a reason why its better left on top. Anyway, this information is good and not included in the previous question. Thanx for answering. :)